# Equivalent of the C# method in java

Tags: c#, java, generics

I am new to programming and trying to translate some c# code to java. I am trying to find out what exactly the below method does. How can I write the same in java.

This is part of an abstract class in C#

```
 //
// Summary:
//     Gets a page object of the desired type that wraps this document.
//
// Type parameters:
//   TPage:
//     The WatiN.Core.Document.Page<T0>() subclass
//
// Returns:
//     The page object
public virtual TPage Page<TPage>() where TPage : Page, new();
```

Comment: Expecting java to have C#-like features is like expecting my 133 MHz 586 machine with 12 MB ram that I used to play Warcraft 1 on when I was 13 to run Windows 8.

Comment: That isn't C# code - replace "virtual" with "abstract" and you have C# code (assuming it's within an abstract class).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas It's probably copied from the results of pressing `F12` on a metghod that's in a referenced assembly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the documentation you provided this would be the best solution since you are likely wanting the type information to lookup the correct page.

```
public <T extends Page> T getPage(Class<T> pageClass)
```

You would then use it like this:

```
MyPage page = myClass.Page(MyPage.class);
```

This design is due to Java's implementation of generics being based around type erasure, so you'll need to pass in the desired type as a parameter to get around it.

Comment: +1 This is the only answer that provides a way to instantiate `T`, so it's as close as one can get from `new()` with Java generics.

Answer (score 0):

```
TPage Page<TPage extends Page>();
```

All methods are virtual by default in java so that part is fine.

Comment: But that doesn't create a method?  Or is that irrelevant based on the C# code?

Comment: But the signature you've defined isn't a valid method signature, but would make a instance variable...just curious ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer oops, do these changes help? There's still a problem of making sure TPage defines a constructor taking 0 parameters, but I don't know if that's possible.

Comment: I think something like `public TPage<? extends Page> getPage()` "might" be closer, but I'm not sure out the need for the generic signature...

Comment: @MadProgrammer This means you can call object1.getPage<TPage1>() and object.getPage<TPage2>() on the same object. It could be used to filter a private list based on type since in C# without type erasure the type is available to do such a thing. I'm by no means a java developer so I'm just going off of old knowledge and some educated guesses.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract <TPage extends Page> TPage Page();
```

But there is no Java equivalent to the "new()" constraint in C#.